# How to convert XAudio2 I3DL2 Model to OpenAL effects?

Tags: c++, audio, openal, xaudio2

I am currently implementing sound in a test program. I am using OpenAL by default because its working an all target platforms I have. On Windows I decided to go with XAudio2.

For reverb effects in XAudio2 you provide a I3DL2 model an convert it a
native XAudio2 model via ReverbConvertI3DL2ToNative. Now my question is: Is there any way to convert an I3DL2 to OpenAL effect settings?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the "I3DL2 presets are included in [efx-presets.h](https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/blob/master/include/AL/efx-presets.h) which match the presets supported by XAudio2.

Comment: But the structure looks different to the one on Xaudio2. Just see XAUDIO2FX_REVERB_I3DL2_PARAMETERS and the same for the output value of the function

Comment: XAUdio2 and OpenAL soft have their own 'native' reverb parameters, but you can just use the shared set of presets to keep your life simple.

Comment: On one hand the structures are really different. So for me it's unclear how to apply id3l2 settings to OpenAL. On the other hand the parameters needs to be converted as I understood from the docs.. I guess it is not that simple.

Comment: You are right there is a section which does have the same parameters. My fault..